# Effect of late penalties on cheating and late submissions

Tags: assessment

Is there any research on the effect of late penalties on both late submissions and academic honesty?  I imagine that having some late penalties will certainly encourage students to get their stuff in on time, but I wonder if the effect is stronger (as in, fewer students submitting late, and more students submitting with plenty of time to spare) with stronger penalties.  But I have no evidence for that.  I also wonder if the strength of the late penalty has anything to do with cheating. Again, I envision a stronger late penalty would encourage more cheating, since there is more to lose by not getting it done, but I have no evidence.

Comment: It seems unlikely that any reliable research exists. First, it is very specialized and second the conditions might well be too variable to draw any general conclusions. Perhaps you can find pedagogy that makes such a question entirely moot.

Comment: Copying and pasting the title of this question into the Google Scholar search box produces a few promising leads (along with some stuff in rather unexpected subject areas).